# Error: Image uploading from sd card to an album in facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, image, android-sdcard

In my facebook android application i need to upload images from sd card to a specific album in facebook. I can create an album with the same name of sd card folder. But after creating album it gets an exception- android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. Here is my code-

```
private void uploadImage() 
{
    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
              .getExternalStorageDirectory()
              .getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/Friends/";


    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();

    for (File file : files)
    {      
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        final byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

        facebook.authorize(MainActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener()         
        {                   
            @Override                   
            public void onComplete(Bundle values)
            {

                if(verify)
                {
                    myAlbumId = createAlbumName();
                    verify=false;
                }
                uploadImagesToAlbum(data, myAlbumId);

            }  

            @Override   
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FaceBook Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override                     
            public void onError(DialogError e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }                      

            @Override                     
            public void onCancel() 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }          
        }); 
    }

}

private String createAlbumName()
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Friends");
    params.putString("message", "My Test Album Description Here");
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/albums", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
    String response = "";
    String albumId = "";
    try {
        response = facebook.request("https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums",params,"POST");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        albumId=Util.parseJson(response).getString("id");
    } catch (FacebookError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return albumId;
}

private void uploadImagesToAlbum(byte[] byteArray, String albumId)
{
    if ( albumId == null ) {
        albumId = "me";
    }
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);
    mAsyncRunner.request(albumId+"/photos", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);


}
```

Here is my log-

> 03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:197)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestImpl(Facebook.java:806)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:794)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.example.androidfacebookpractice.MainActivity.createAlbumName(MainActivity.java:340)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.example.androidfacebookpractice.MainActivity.access$4(MainActivity.java:331)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.example.androidfacebookpractice.MainActivity$9.onComplete(MainActivity.java:290)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.onSessionCallback(Facebook.java:345)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.access$11(Facebook.java:326)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook$1.call(Facebook.java:304)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.facebook.Session$3$1.run(Session.java:1179)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   03-24 04:06:27.954: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

How can i upload images to the album? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your log so that all can help you..

Its connection error not image uploading error.

U cant connect directly put all your network access on a thread or handler or asynctask .

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
I solve this problem using a new Thread

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Your code goes here
            }                               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i get error when keep the thread to @Override                   
public void onComplete(Bundle values)